# K-Means Clustering issue regarding Centroids

Tags: python, k-means

So I am having trouble with my script below, code runs and compiles, but there are some issues. I am not sure if my issue is a calculation issue or if its formatting issue. I am not even sure if I am on the right track, I feel like I am but I am new to python, I am all ears to any advice or input would be awesome! Stuck on the following:

1) The K_means class does not assign centroids to clusters at all

2) The K_means class does not perform any recalculations to re-center the centroids

Below is my code, I just pasted my functions since i think that is where the problem lies:

```
class K_means():
    def __init__(self,k, lines, **kwargs):
        self.k = k
        self.lines = lines 
        self.index = []
        self.distance = []
        self.elements = []
        self.points = []
        for keys, values in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, keys, values)

    def determineDistance(self, centroids, new_dict):

        for keys, points in new_dict.items():
            self.points.append(points)
            for elements in range(len(centroids)):
                self.elements.append(elements)
                distance = abs(points - centroids[elements])
                self.distance.append(distance)


    def assign_to_clusters(self, lines, clusters, centroids, 
        point_assignments, distance, new_dict):

        for index, points in new_dict.items():
            closest_index = (self.k + 1)
            for elements in range(len(centroids)):
                distance = self.determineDistance(centroids, new_dict)
                if distance < closest_index:
                    closest_index = distance
                    index = elements
            clusters[index].append(points)
            point_assignments[index] = closest_index
        return point_assignments

    def update_location(self, clusters, centroids):
        for keys, values in clusters.items():
            new_centroids ={keys:sum(values)/float(len(values))} 
            centroids.update(new_centroids)
        return centroids
```

Comment: You posted too much code. Please create [an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @DYZ, I have updated with less code and where I think the problem lies. thanks!